# Querying for Shares?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-sharing

Is there a way to query/filter for data shares in a Snowflake account? I know that you can use below two queries to display information:

```sql
SHOW SHARES;

DESC SHARE my_share;
```

But I cannot use above to filter results (with a `where` clause). Is there any place like the `information_schema` where I can simply query about shares and filter on the output columns? For example, I would like to query for all outbound shares that are sharing a particular table.

Note: I did run into [result_scan](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan) option, but I am looking for direct way to query. It feels a bit hacky to use this approach and also not sure if it will work from application code where there could be many queries running in parallel.

Comment: You can get the results safely and unambiguously if you can get the query ID. For example, in Python you can get the query ID from a "cursor" object: https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#retrieving-the-snowflake-query-id

Comment: You should be able to just write a UDTF that wraps round the SHOW SHARES command and returns the results as a table - so you can include it in a standard SQL statement

Comment: There really should be an account_usage view for this, but there isn't.  I would recommend reaching out to your account team to request this.  The more customers that ask for it, the more likely Snowflake is to implement it.